# Program has exited with code -2147483645

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Ive run into an interesting (rather annoying) error while using Visual Studio to debug a mixed WPF/CLR/Unmanaged native c++ project, this error occurs only in Windows XP.  It would seem that I have a memory corruption occuring within the program, the scope of which is much too large to post here.  The problem that I am having is that when the crash occurs in the program, it simply exits without the VS debugger attempting to locate an exception, I assume because none is thrown.  The program exit code is really the only information I have to go on, and its just the minimum int value.

Has anyone encountered this and might be able to point me in the right direction as far as what it means?

EDIT:

Continuing to investigate the problem, Ive discovered that I can sometimes get a stack trace and an exception as opposed to a straight program exit.  The trace brings me to a vector allocation (push).  In the scenario where the program just exits, this is still the last line executed.  I assume that I have corrupt memory somewhere, though I was hoping that the fact that this usually manifests itself as a program dump and not an exception would be able to help point me in the right direction.

Comment: is there an exit() statement or a throw from a descturcor both of these I have see cause the indicated behavior.

Comment: the exit code may make more sense interpreted as an HRESULT ==> 0x80000003

Comment: @rerun you might be on to something with a throw from a destructor, Ill look into it.

Comment: @jglouie Thank you for your suggestion, not sure what you mean though

Comment: `-2147483645` is not the minimum int value; it's -2**31 + 3. If it's an HRESULT, `0x80000003`, it's `E_INVALIDARG`, "One or more arguments are invalid".

Comment: @KeithThompson Thank you for your help, I assume there are numerous possible causes for this error, why is this flag passed through an exit code and not caught by the debugger?  Do you have any suggestions on how I might attempt to locate the cause?

Comment: @jimmyjambles: I can only guess, but perhaps the program is just written incorrectly, returning an HRESULT from `main()` or passing it to `exit()`. Take a look at your `main()` function.

Comment: @KeithThompson As I mentioned, I am running this code through a dll.  There is no main() function and no exit is being called.  Furthermore, this issue is only occuring on Windows XP clients.  This is production level library currently being used, this bug was recently introduced so it has nothing to with the structure of the program.  Though as a statement of fact, bugs generally occur because programs are "just written incorrectly".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
//
// MessageId: STATUS_BREAKPOINT
//
// MessageText:
//
// {EXCEPTION}
// Breakpoint
// A breakpoint has been reached.
//
#define STATUS_BREAKPOINT                ((NTSTATUS)0x80000003L)
```

The program landed on an INT3 instruction and triggered a breakpoint.  But no debugger present so that terminates the program.  It could be a stray __debugbreak() you left in your code, it could be triggered by a wild jump when the program state got corrupted.

You'll need to debug it.  If you can't easily repro it on your dev machine then you'll need a minidump from the failing machine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I went as far as installing Visual Studio on a Windows XP VM.  Re-compiled and ran locally with a debugger present, program still just exits.  The last line that gets called is an allocation.

Comment: I don't know, that's not typical behavior for XP.  Sounds like heap corruption of course.  Debug + Exceptions, tick the Thrown boxes.

Comment: was accessing a byte past an upper array bound, I guess what through me off was the lack of anything thrown.  Thanks again