# C# PInvoke of C++ function that returns struct by value crashes if the struct is left uninitialized

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035826/why-dllimport-for-c-bool-as-unmanagedtype-i1-throws-but-as-byte-it-works) they use a bool which can have variable size between platforms. No such thing is going on here. The struct is blittable.

The method crashes on return if the struct is left uninitialized - I'm not sure why. Suppose I wanted to return a struct with random content. Is it simply that this is invalid C++?

C++:

```
struct H { uint32_t x; };

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) H _cdecl GetH() {
  std::cout << "get-h called" << std::endl;
  H h{5}; // works if this is used
  // H h; // fails if this is used
  return h;
}
```

C#:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct H {
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
  public UInt32 X;
}

[DllImport("mydll.dll", EntryPoint = "GetH", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern H GetH();

void Test() { 
  H h = GetH();
  Console.WriteLine(h.X);
}
```

Output without initializer h{5}:

```
  get-h called
  Test.exe exited with code -2147483645
```

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583957/program-has-exited-with-code-2147483645

Comment: @Bernd, the user on that message link ultimately finds that he had memory corruption due to buffer overflow. In my case, I think the compiler is behaving differently to cause the problem; there's hardly any code for a bug.

Comment: The code looks not really wrong - so it is hard to say anything to it. One thing is maybe the calling convention it seems to be "__cdecl" instead of "_cdecl":
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/cpp/cpp/cdecl?view=msvc-160

Which compiler do you use (I assume MSVC because of declspec but it could be clang, too).
We need the compiler flags...

And you should use `int32_t` or `uint32_t`  just to be sure that `int` is 32 bits.
If you are on windows you can check the eventlog, too.

Comment: _cdecl seems to be okay

Comment: After reading the question you said this isn't a dupe of, I agree that this is definitely a dupe of that question, and you need to reread the _answers_ on that page.

Comment: Even if you _do_ initialize the C++ struct with something like -1, it'll likely show up on the receiver side as 4294967295 because your types don't match. Edit: Now the types match so "only" the UB remains.

Comment: @MooingDuck, No, this is a blittable structure. It works fine (and is a supported use case!) as long as the struct is initialized - the problem was that returning `h` uninitialized is not valid C++.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, Thanks, I fixed the sign in the post. This was a simplified demo, not my actual use case, and I mixed it up when transcribing. My main concern was the crash though, which is resolved by initialization.

Comment: @evo8198 Yes, a crash is one possible outcome of UB. I prefer crashes over programs that _appears_ to be working, so - you were in luck :-)

Comment: Large negative exit codes are useful, they tell you why the program failed.  Convert to hex to get 0x80000003, that's STATUS_BREAKPOINT, "A breakpoint has been reached".  Maybe you programmed debugbreak() intentionally in order to debug the native code, maybe the C++ runtime is trying to tell you something.  Project > Properties > Debug tab > tick "Enable native code debugging" to get to listen to it.  Also the way to not require debugbreak(), a normal breakpoint in the native code now works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the code was compiled debug-mode and runtime checks for (lack of) variable initialization were setting a breakpoint. Since this was P-invoked and I was attached to the calling C#, I couldn't see what was going on in the C++ and it was simply exiting with error code 0x80000003, as @HansPassant points out. Once I enabled native code debugging in Visual Studio, the exception became clear and the process no longer terminated abruptly.

Also, release-mode compilation takes out the runtime checks (/RTC compile flag) and this wouldn't be an issue in release mode. So return of an uninitialized struct actually does work in practice.